# Is it possible to know when a new object of any given type is created?

Tags: c#, types

Is there any way to set up a kind of observer to know if, within my app domain, a new object of a given X type is creates, I mean to detect when a class is instantiated.

What a would like to do (in a pink world) is something like the following:

```
public class BlackBoxObserver<T> where T : class
{
    public event Action SomewhereBeyondYourSightAInstanceHasBeenCreated;

    public void StartTracking()
    {
        //todo black magic...
    }

    protected virtual void OnSomewhereBeyondYourSightAInstanceHasBeenCreated()
        => SomewhereBeyondYourSightAInstanceHasBeenCreated?.Invoke();
}
```

And then using it:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var dictionaryObserver = new BlackBoxObserver<Dictionary<string,string>>();
        dictionaryObserver.StartTracking();
        dictionaryObserver.SomewhereBeyondYourSightAInstanceHasBeenCreated +=
            () => Console.WriteLine("Dictionary created somewhere!");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Why does it have  to be black magic inside StartTracking? Why not just log the DateTime and have some process watch that?

Comment: What would that process be watching? How do I know when a new Dictionary<string, string> is created? or any other type...

Comment: @MatthewEvans If you know how to detect types instantiations then do some black magic, because I tried to figure out a way (without factories) but couldn't find anything..

Comment: maybe logger a datetime field that is initiated in constructor to now? or logger that logs datetime in constructor?

Comment: What is the need to detect object instantiation in the first place?

Comment: @YahyaHussein, that would work for my own classes only, as you may know we do not have access to Dictionary constructor or many others .Net types

Comment: @Alejandro, I think that is not relevant, the question is about if this can be done anyway.

Comment: @taquion in this case put the logger just before or after the instantiation

Comment: have you looked if windows gives some kind of meta data for memory allocation process?

Comment: @YahyaHussein, I think putting the logger just before is not robust enough. Suppouse I wan to know if a certain .NET method instantiate a certain type. I have not looked for the metadata you mention, although I hope it exists. Think about profileres for instance. There must be a way

Comment: There is always a way, the question is if its relatively easy. I don't think there is but I might be wrong.

Comment: @taquion No idea if it's relevant or not, knowing the use case would help determine if it's the best thing to do or not. I have a strong suspicion this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).